# acessing global varibale in multiprocess loop

Tags: python, windows, loops, multiprocessing

I don't know what's going on?! and it's weird so can you explain why and fix it?
im trying to run multiprocessing in a 2 loops and for the sake of reducing computations I need to calculate some global variables i.e. 'ga' and 'gb' but in the functions 'sirgr' which goes into multiprocessing the ga and gb get crooked. ga to (last range of loop 1 minus 1 plus100 I mean 107) and gb also (last range of loop 2 minus 1  plus100 I mean 123) so what is going on? the `global ga,gb` also don't make any help.
I know ofc I can send it to functions but I need global.

```
import multiprocessing
def sirgr(row,col):
    global ga,gb
    print('sirgr',ga,gb)
    return ((row,col),(ga,gb))
def main():
    print('mainf',ga,gb)
    if __name__=="__main__":
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            print('ino',tupleinput)
            output = list(pool.starmap(sirgr,tupleinput))
            print('out',output)
process_num=2
tupleinput=[]
for row in range(8):
    ga=row+100
    for col in range(20,24):
        gb=col+100
        print("r",row,'c',col)
        print('mainit',ga,gb)
        tupleinput.append((row,col))
        if len(tupleinput)==process_num:
            main()
            tupleinput=[]
```

results:

```
#############
r 0 c 20
mainit 100 120
r 0 c 21
mainit 100 121
mainf 100 121
ino [(0, 20), (0, 21)]
out [((0, 20), (107, 123)), ((0, 21), (107, 123))]
#############
r 0 c 22
mainit 100 122
r 0 c 23
mainit 100 123
mainf 100 123
ino [(0, 22), (0, 23)]
out [((0, 22), (107, 123)), ((0, 23), (107, 123))]
....
#############
r 7 c 20
mainit 107 120
r 7 c 21
mainit 107 121
mainf 107 121
ino [(7, 20), (7, 21)]
out [((7, 20), (107, 123)), ((7, 21), (107, 123))]
#############
r 7 c 22
mainit 107 122
r 7 c 23
mainit 107 123
mainf 107 123
ino [(7, 22), (7, 23)]
out [((7, 22), (107, 123)), ((7, 23), (107, 123))]
```

for example in output after `r 0 c 21` output expected to be

`out [((0, 20), (100, 121)), ((0, 21), (100, 121))]`

but it is

`out [(({row}, {col-1}), (107, 123)), (({row}, {col}), (107, 123))]` for all outputs
but I should have been

`out [(({row}, {col-1}), ({row}, {col+100})), (({row}, {col}), {col+100})]`

Comment: has anyone ran this code to see results?

Comment: Nobody seems to follow the guidelines of tagging the question with the platform they are running on when posting question with the *multiprocessing* tag. **if you are running on Windows, your ` if __name__=="__main__":` is in the wrong place.**

Comment: @Booboo so where should I put it? if `len(tupleinput)==process_num:
             if _name__=="_main__":
            main()`??!

Comment: The point is that any code at global scope will be executed by *each* process in your pool before the first worker function, `sirgr`, is called. That would be all the code starting with `process_num=2` and below including the loop that begins `for col in range(20,24):` within which function `q` is called. Does it make sense to move `if __name__=="__main__":` so that all of this code is within a block that begins with this?

Comment: By the way, you are creating the pool over and over in a loop. If you move the `if` statement so all the code I mentioned is within it, you should create the pool once (do not use `with` because we do not want to implicitly call `terminate` on the pool unless the nested `for` loops are within the `with` block) within that block prior to the loop and pass the pool to `main` so it can be used over and over again without recreating.

Comment: But you have a bigger problem thinking you can change global variables `ga` and `gb` in your main process and think it will be reflected in the address spaces of your subprocesses. You need to pass these as parameters to your worker function `sirgr`.

Comment: @Booboo can you make example of what you are saying or re-write what you mean quickly cuz I have problem understanding some of your sayings.

Comment: Im looking to calculate 'ga' once and use it  for my second loop. they do some multiprocessing with ga for each of elements in second loop.

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You did not supply a `q` function, so I created my own.

See my comment about not being able to modifying regular global variables in the main process and expecting them to appear changed in subprocess's addrss space. If you insist on using global variables, these have to be *managed*, *shared* variables. Their actual values have to be accessed via their `value` attribute.

Note: Your code was only calling `starmap` with two tuples at a time, which is really not the most efficient way of proceeding unless, of course, you only have two CPU cores but even then it is still better to queue up all your tasks and call `starmap` once -- there will be less idle time. Since you are creating the pool with no arguments, it will create a pool size equal to the number of CPU cores that you have, which may very well be greater than two. You should therefore take advantage of whatever CPUs you have.

```py
import multiprocessing

def q(*args):
    args = [str(arg) for arg in args]
    print(', '.join(args))

def init_pool(globala, globalb):
    global ga, gb
    ga = globala
    gb = globalb

def sirgr(row, col):
    q('sirgr', ga.value, gb.value)
    return ((row,col),(ga.value, gb.value))

def main(pool, tupleinput):
    q('mainf', ga.value, gb.value)
    q('ino',tupleinput)
    output = pool.starmap(sirgr, tupleinput)
    q('out',output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        ga = manager.Value('i', 0)
        gb = manager.Value('i', 0)
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(ga, gb))
        tupleinput=[]
        for row in range(8):
            ga.value = row+100
            for col in range(20,24):
                gb.value = col+100
                q("r", row, 'c', col)
                q('mainit',ga.value, gb.value)
                tupleinput.append((row, col))
        main(pool, tupleinput)
```

Prints:

```
r, 0, c, 20
mainit, 100, 120
r, 0, c, 21
mainit, 100, 121
r, 0, c, 22
mainit, 100, 122
r, 0, c, 23
mainit, 100, 123
r, 1, c, 20
mainit, 101, 120
r, 1, c, 21
mainit, 101, 121
r, 1, c, 22
mainit, 101, 122
r, 1, c, 23
mainit, 101, 123
r, 2, c, 20
mainit, 102, 120
r, 2, c, 21
mainit, 102, 121
r, 2, c, 22
mainit, 102, 122
r, 2, c, 23
mainit, 102, 123
r, 3, c, 20
mainit, 103, 120
r, 3, c, 21
mainit, 103, 121
r, 3, c, 22
mainit, 103, 122
r, 3, c, 23
mainit, 103, 123
r, 4, c, 20
mainit, 104, 120
r, 4, c, 21
mainit, 104, 121
r, 4, c, 22
mainit, 104, 122
r, 4, c, 23
mainit, 104, 123
r, 5, c, 20
mainit, 105, 120
r, 5, c, 21
mainit, 105, 121
r, 5, c, 22
mainit, 105, 122
r, 5, c, 23
mainit, 105, 123
r, 6, c, 20
mainit, 106, 120
r, 6, c, 21
mainit, 106, 121
r, 6, c, 22
mainit, 106, 122
r, 6, c, 23
mainit, 106, 123
r, 7, c, 20
mainit, 107, 120
r, 7, c, 21
mainit, 107, 121
r, 7, c, 22
mainit, 107, 122
r, 7, c, 23
mainit, 107, 123
mainf, 107, 123
ino, [(0, 20), (0, 21), (0, 22), (0, 23), (1, 20), (1, 21), (1, 22), (1, 23), (2, 20), (2, 21), (2, 22), (2, 23), (3, 20), (3, 21), (3, 22), (3, 23), (4, 20), (4, 21), (4, 22), (4, 23), (5, 20), (5, 21), (5, 22), (5, 23), (6, 20), (6, 21), (6, 22), (6, 23), (7, 20), (7, 21), (7, 22), (7, 23)]
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
sirgr, 107, 123
out, [((0, 20), (107, 123)), ((0, 21), (107, 123)), ((0, 22), (107, 123)), ((0, 23), (107, 123)), ((1, 20), (107, 123)), ((1, 21), (107, 123)), ((1, 22), (107, 123)), ((1, 23), (107, 123)), ((2, 20), (107, 123)), ((2, 21), (107, 123)), ((2, 22), (107, 123)), ((2, 23), (107, 123)), ((3, 20), (107, 123)), ((3, 21), (107, 123)), ((3, 22), (107, 123)), ((3, 23), (107, 123)), ((4, 20), (107, 123)), ((4, 21), (107, 123)), ((4, 22), (107, 123)), ((4, 23), (107, 123)), ((5, 20), (107, 123)), ((5, 21), (107, 123)), ((5, 22), (107, 123)), ((5, 23), (107, 123)), ((6, 20), (107, 123)), ((6, 21), (107, 123)), ((6, 22), (107, 123)), ((6, 23), (107, 123)), ((7, 20), (107, 123)), ((7, 21), (107, 123)), ((7, 22), (107, 123)), ((7, 23), (107, 123))]
```

**Update**

If you really want to submit tasks two at a time, then (the assumption is that the total number of tasks to submit is a multiple of 2):

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        ga = manager.Value('i', 0)
        gb = manager.Value('i', 0)
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(ga, gb))
        tupleinput=[]
        for row in range(8):
            ga.value = row+100
            for col in range(20,24):
                gb.value = col+100
                q("r", row, 'c', col)
                q('mainit',ga.value, gb.value)
                tupleinput.append((row, col))
                if len(tupleinput) == 2:
                    main(pool, tupleinput)
                    tupleinput = []
```

**Update 2**

I just happened to be re-visiting this and saw I was using *managed* `Value` instances for `ga` and `gb`, which work, but have more overhead than *shared memory* `Value` instances, which for this problem are all you need:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ga = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0, Lock=False) # no synchronization required
    gb = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0, Lock=False) # no synchronization required
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(ga, gb))
    ... # etc.
```

Comment: thank you so much also these are not exactly what I wrote but  really close enough to what I wanted. I should reread what u said and maybe ask questions later.

Comment: I would make it final answer later. thanx again

Comment: I've added an update showing how to do it one tuple at a time (but calling `starmap` repeatedly is less efficient -- you only need a pool size of 1 and you ate *not* multiprocessing).

Comment: no no no, I want go to multiprocessing after each loop and use ga and gb as global variables, I knew it I could send them explicitly to my func "sirgr" but in order to not change my so many other functions I need "ga" and "gb" recognized globally within "sirgr". so this is not my answer.

Comment: This will *not* work with regular Python global varibales. You will need to use *shared* variables. I will get back to you on this.

Comment: I've updated the answer. This is really the best you can do using global variables.